# Jquery Validation plugin and Colorbox

Tags: validation, forms, jquery, colorbox

Does anyone know the best way to get the Jquery Validation plugin to run when submitting a form that has been loaded dynamically into a Jquery Colorbox modal window?

Answer (score 6):

Add the validation set up to the colorbox callback. That way the color box has been loaded and the form exists before you attempt to set up validation for it.

```
 $('selector').colorbox({...options...}, function() {
     $('form',this).validate( {...options...} );
 });
```

Comment: I was sure I'd tried that as my first port of call, must of had something wrong somewhere. All working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with this and found a better solution (at least for myself).

```
$('selector').colorbox(
     {options, onComplete:function(){$('selector').validate({}
});
```

Visually I can see when the lightbox is finished loading, it'll attach this function to the lightbox.  It's the same as what tvanfosson posted, but I like mine for readability purposes.